# Why is iterator not starting at initial position

Tags: python, python-3.x

My custom iterator is not starting at the initial position:

```
class XYpositions:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pos = (0,0)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.pos = (self.pos[0]+1, self.pos[1])
        if self.pos[0] >= self.width:
            self.pos = (0, self.pos[1]+1)
        if self.pos[1] >= self.height:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.pos

for pos in XYpositions(2, 3):
    print(pos)
```

yields

```
(1, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
```

What?? Where is the (0,0)?

Comment: Where in the code should (0,0) be returned? Before or after starting to add 1 to `self.pos[0]`?

Comment: `__next__` is called for _each_ iteration, _including_ the first.

Comment: I see that IS what is happening. Then why the heck is the tuturial initializing at the initial position (instead of -1) https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_iterator_create

Comment: @WurmD Note how that example is saving the current value before incrementing it.

Comment: *loud-facepalm*

Comment: and you might as well answer @RocketHazmat :) 200k reputation non-withstanding XD

Comment: @WurmD I did post an answer, but I deleted it because you posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Rocket pointed out, `__next__` is called for *each* iteration, *including* the first.

If one wishes for the iterator to start at the initialized position, then one must save the current position in `__next__` before incrementing it like so:

```
def __next__(self):
    current_pos = self.pos
    self.pos = (self.pos[0]+1, self.pos[1])
    if self.pos[0] >= self.width:
        self.pos = (0, self.pos[1]+1)
    if current_pos[1] >= self.height:
        raise StopIteration
    return current_pos
```

Comment: This ends the iteration one step too early. You want the last `if` block, that can `raise` to be considering the saved `current_pos` from the previous calculation, not the new one. Move it to the top of the function and you'll get the right results (ending with `1, 2` as the last valid output).